# Why annotation processor doesn't work with Maven and java11?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, java-11, annotation-processing

I'm migrating a Java webapp from Java8 to Java17.
This project uses this very nice solution to embed strings (ex. SQL queries) in constanst:
https://github.com/adrianwalker/multiline-string
This library requires the annotation processor.

With the old version I could run "mvn clean install" to get the war file of my application, this process correctly processed annotations. I had just to add the library in the pom dependencies.

Now using java17 the annotation doesn't work. Then I tried to use in my Eclipse IDE and here the compilation doesn't work too.

Then I tried to downgrade to Java11 and I could start the project from Eclipse, setting the library as annotation processor in java compile option of Eclipse.
Finally I tried the maven install, it completed successfully but the annotations are not processed.

This is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>MyApp</groupId>
    <artifactId>MyApp</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <finalName>ROOT</finalName>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.so</include>
                    <include>**/*.dll</include>
                    <include>**/*.xml</include>
                    <include>**/*.jrxml</include>
            </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                  <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
            <artifactId>jna</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-websocket</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-messaging</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
            <version>1.60</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
            <version>6.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-net</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-net</artifactId>
            <version>3.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcpkix-jdk15on</artifactId>
            <version>1.60</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
            <version>4.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-text</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.barcode4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>barcode4j</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>
            <artifactId>javase</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
            <artifactId>batik-bridge</artifactId>
            <version>1.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports-fonts</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.lyncode</groupId>
            <artifactId>jtwig-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>8.5.38</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.15</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-ri</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.adrianwalker</groupId>
            <artifactId>multiline-string</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.2</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${projectPath}\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\multilineo-string-0.1.2b.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
       <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-netty</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.w3c</groupId>
            <artifactId>dom</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0-jaxb-1.0.6</version>
        </dependency>       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-rabbit</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

I also tried to add this option in maven compilter plugin settings of pom.xml

```
<configuration>
          <annotationProcessors>
            <annotationProcessor>
              org.adrianwalker.multilinestring.MultilineProcessor</annotationProcessor>
          </annotationProcessors>
  </configuration>
```

I cannot understand why Eclipse can compile and run the application with annotations, it can also **export** valid ROOT.war, but Maven ignores (without errors) completely the annotations.

Do you have any idea why maven doesnt run the annotation processor?
Do you know how can I get the eclipse command called when I export WAR file from a project?

EDIT

These are the versions:
Apache Maven 3.8.7
Java version: 17.0.7
Eclipse Version: 2023-03 (4.27.0)
M2E Maven Integration for Eclipse: 2.2.1.20230307-1553

Comment: Why have you change `<sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>`? Keep the defaults. Also why using soo much spring framework... why not directly using spring boot and packaging to WAR file... etc.?

Comment: Hmm, what version of Eclipse was this? And of Maven? And the M2Eclipse plug-ins?

Comment: You know that Java 17 supports multi line strings directly in code? This is called text blocks. I would suggest refactor your code to these instead.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen this is great news, I don't know if we are able to refactor, but I would absolutely consider it!

Comment: @nitind thanks for your notice, I'm updating the question with versions.

Comment: @khmarbaise thanks for your tips, this project has a long history and was started when SpringBoot did not exist. To be honest we don't need an embedded application server so I don't know how much advantages will bring a migration to Boot. BTW I think this is a useful discussion but a bit offtopic, because for sure annotations processing is not spring dependent.

Comment: Annotation processors are not supposed to modify the source code. The standard API doesn’t offer such features. Hence, this annotation processor can only work by accessing compiler internals which can change between versions.

Comment: Finally I could refactor to java native multi line string. I was faster than find a solution. Thanks everybody

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java 17 supports multi line strings directly in code (so-called *text blocks*).

Instead of making some ancient hack work again, just refactor to modern Java.